# Поиск ссылки на видео через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

Распарсив страницу я получила нужный кусок :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как теперь  обратиться к "data-videoconfig", что бы достать 'url'?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так: переводим ваш кусок в строку `html = str(soup)`, после чего узнаем индекс первого найденного символа `{`, и индекс последнего символа `}`.
С помощью индексов срезаем текст и десериализируем строку (получаем dict и обращаемся по ключу).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html_doc = """<div class="my_class" data-videoconfig="{"result":{"hello":"world"}}"></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup (html_doc, 'html.parser')
html = str(soup)
my_json = json.loads(html[html.find('{'):html.rfind('}')+1])
print(my_json[' result']['hello'])
```